# Access datepicker with python2.7 and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

I'm trying to specify the dates on a datepicker from this application:

http://www.wetter-by.de/Internet/AM/inetcntrBY.nsf/cuhome.xsp?src=4JHVFJGNW4&p1=535TN12L42&p3=2CQ7BH7901&p4=4D078O1691

Though, I wasn't able to switch to the iframe, because Firefox would only give me the absolute xpath. Also, Chropath does not seem to work on this particular iframe. Instead, I switch to the direct link:

http://dlr45.aspdienste.de/cgi-bin/wdaasc/wdaa_client.pl?cid=7

The datepicker takes numbers by typing, too, so I tried to specify my dates by sending keys. This is my first try:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://dlr45.aspdienste.de/cgi-bin/wdaasc/wdaa_client.pl?cid=7')
browser.maximize_window()

select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('sid'))
select.select_by_index(2)

from_date = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='from']")
from_date.send_keys("01102016")
from_date.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The error states that the Element is not reachable by keyboard, so I accessed the calendar directly, here is my second try:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://dlr45.aspdienste.de/cgi-bin/wdaasc/wdaa_client.pl?cid=7')
browser.maximize_window()

select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('sid'))
select.select_by_index(2)

from_date =  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='from']")

#Specify year
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(from_date).click().send_keys("2016").perform()

WebDriverWait(browser,4)

#Jump to Oktober
for i in np.arange(9):
    next_month = browser.find_element_by_class_name('ui-datepicker-next')
    next_month.click()

day = browser.find_element_by_class_name('ui-state-default')
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(day).send_keys('01').perform()
```

So far, the month and the year are correctly picked, and it looks like the 1st of October is being selected, but not clicked.

Is there an easy way to send the dates (like in my first try)? If not, how can I click the day, as in the second? I don't need the iframe-switch anymore but if someone has any idea how to find the xpath I would appreciate it.